# Unable to add same object twice using VB Script

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add objects in excel using a VB Script, but it gives 1004 error after inserting first object stating file is still open. VB script which i am using is posted below. Please suggest me on how to debug it.

```
    Sub Macro2()
    '
    ' Deepak Macro
    '

    '

        Range("H2").Select
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:="C:\localhost.localdomain.csv", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon _
            :=True, IconFileName:= _
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", IconIndex:=13, _
            IconLabel:="C:\localhost.localdomain.csv").Select

        Range("H3").Select
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:="C:\localhost.localdomain.csv", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon _
            :=True, IconFileName:= _
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", IconIndex:=13, _
            IconLabel:="C:\localhost.localdomain.csv").Select

    End Sub
```

Comment: If there is a file by the name `localhost.localdomain.csv` at the location `C:\ ` then the above lines of code should work (tested on my machine with Windows 10 and Office 2013 64 bit). All I can think of is to make sure that `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` really is the correct path to the program (and not `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`).

Comment: localhost.localdomain.csv is placed properly and iexplorer.exe is at proper location still i am getting 1004 error

Comment: Sorry, but in that case this is an error I cannot reproduce and therefore I am unable to help you any further. Could you please post your system settings: Windows Version XP, 7, 8.1, 10, Excel Version 2003, 2007, 2013, 2016, 32-bit / 64-bit? Maybe then we can possibly reproduce the error and help you.

Comment: I am using windows 10 enterprise

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit? Also, please include your Excel version.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Enterprise 64bit, excel is 32bit